# Mounting a binary/shell file that returns files modified in the past x days

Tags: linux, mount, find

I know that you can find files in a path and sub directories modified in the past week with:

```
find -L /somepath -mtime -5 -type f
```

I could assign that to a job and have it run every night to create symlinks to those files in a particular folder using `-exec` ... That's not the purpose of my question though.

I'd like to know if it's possible to "emulate" a disk/folder and make a file mountable (like a smart ISO?) that would return a list of those files automatically, or if this application has already been done?  (I've been looking, but not finding it.)

Comment: You can (rather easily, I am told) implement a minimal filesystem using FUSE yourself. You should be familiar with C though.

Comment: @Daniel Beck - I'd have some serious brush up to do on my C to do that I think.  (I haven't done C in years...)  If no answers come in I may have to look into this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach besides FUSE is to create a small program (again using C or maybe Google Go) which is using inotify system calls to monitor the filesystem, filters relevant events and keeps tmpfs filesystem full of symlinks in actual state.

Comment: Selected your answer as the correct one.  I did not find a way to do this so I reverted to a cron job to create symlinks every couple hours in a specific folder.